# How to get email from twitter by fabric in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, email, twitter, authentication, twitter-fabric

I integrate Fabric sdk for twitter integration and my twitter app is also whitelisted. But also i can not get email of current user also i done code of "TWTRShareEmailViewController" but i didn't get email of user.

Comment: You need to whitelist your app

Comment: My app is already whitelist. @AvijitNagare